# is there a get columns NOT displayed method in ag-grid?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

I'd like to display the headerName in the details section for columns that are NOT displayed. I see documentation on getColumns, displayedColumns, etc., but is there a getHiddenColumns that is up to date with our preference change?

I've tried

```
this.detailHeadings = [];
      ((this.columnDefs).forEach)(element => {
        if (element.hide == true) {
        this.detailHeadings.push(element.headerName);
      }
```

but it takes columnDefs from what I defined it to be, but I'd like it to change with the user preference, like when they hid it or show it again.